# How to find minimum value in a particular row in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix that looks like this:

M = [2 3 4; 2 4 6; 1 5 3]

How do I find the minimum value in each row? For example, I would first want to find the minimum value of the first row? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`min`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/min.html?refresh=true)

```
>> M = [2 3 4; 2 4 6; 1 5 3];
>> X=min(M')

X =

     2     2     1 % row-wise
```

OR

```
>> [E,I] = min(M,[],2) ; % E- Elements, I- Index
```

Answer (score 2):

You also can try
`M = min(A(n,:));` %where `n` is the row you want to look at